# Passing arrays to 2 functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function

So I am supposed to write a program which creates and array and calls function 3 in main, gets 10 integers from user in function 2, and in function 3 it displays values from function 2 in reverse order. I am not sure if the rest is correct, but I have no idea how to get function 3 working (what I have now is absolutely wrong, just a guess):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void function2 (int [], int);
void function3 (int [], int);

int main ()
{
    const int size1 = 10;
    int arr[size1];
    function3(arr, size1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void function2 (int array2[], int size2)
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    cin >> array2[i];
}

void function3 (int array3[], int size3)
{
    size3= 10;
    function2(arr, size3);
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    array2[i]=array3[10-i];
}
```

Comment: In `function3`, `function2(arr, size3);` won't work since `arr` is not defined in the scope. Do you mean to use `array3` instead?

Comment: I don't know .. I want to call values from function 2 and display them in inverse order - array2[0]=array3[9], array2[1]=array3[8] etc.

Comment: `function3` does not have access to `array2` either, so that also does not work.

Comment: I changed arr to array3 and one error is gone, but there is one left (array 2 undefined), I don't know how to make function 3 access array2

Comment: `function2` *modifies* the array. Think about that. Also, you should be checking against `size2` or `size3` and not hard-coding `10` in your `for` loops.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Three minor changes will make this work:

```
function2(arr, size3);
```

should be

```
function2(array3, size3);
```

and

```
array2[i]=array3[10-i];
```

should be

```
cout << array3[9-i];
```

plus any spaces or line breaks you want to add between outputs.

Edit: crashmstr pointed out I was wrong about heap allocating. You would not do that here.

Comment: No, in this case it would not be a good practice to dynamically allocate the array.

Comment: This works the best, just one small change and it works.. thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that according to your assignment you have to output the array in reverse order. It does not mean that you have to reverse the array itself.
Also you should know that there is standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` declared in header `<algorithm>` that could be used for your assignment.

The program can look like

```
#include <iostream>

void function2( int [], size_t );
void function3( int [], size_t );

int main()
{
    const size_t size = 10;
    int arr[size];

    function3( arr, size );

    return 0;
}

void function2( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i];
}

void function3( int a[], size_t n )
{
    function2( a, n );

    for ( size_t i = n; i != 0; i-- ) std::cout << a[i-1] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If to enter

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

then output will be

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```